# ArrayList and .add() method in java

Tags: java, arraylist

I am writing a program that has to read information from file and put them into ArrayList, I think my code is right but Eclipse is saying :`The method add(int, String[]) in the type ArrayList<String[]> is not applicable for the arguments (int, String)` about `account.add(0, x[0]);` in my code.

**My code:**

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    ArrayList<String[]> account = new ArrayList<>();
    String line = "";
    try {
        FileReader fr=new FileReader("information.txt");

        Scanner information = new Scanner(fr);
        while (information.hasNext()) {

            // find next line
            line = information.next();

            String x[]=line.split("-");
            account.add(0, x[0]);
            account.add(0, x[1]);
            account.add(0, x[2]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want each element in the list to be the data for one line of your file, or do you want each line to be transformed into three elements?

Comment: You have a `try` block without a `catch` (or a `finally` block or a resource initialisation).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the signature of the method you're using :

```
public void add(int index, E element) { ... }
```

You have `ArrayList<String[]>`, so the method expects an array of Strings as a second param.
And what you provide is just a String (element from the array).

Try this:

```
String x[]=line.split("-");
account.add(0, x); // because x is actually an array
```

Or you can use it like that:

```
account.add(x);
```

If you still need to put elements from the array into your list like you do here:

```
account.add(0, x[0]);
account.add(0, x[1]);
account.add(0, x[2]);
```

try to change `ArrayList<String[]>` to `ArrayList<String>`.

And just a comment that has nothing to do with your question :)
This is a better practice:

```
// use interface List in the left part :)
List<String[]> account = new ArrayList<>();
```

Happy hacking :)

Answer (score 0):

You should to just write `account.add(x[0]);`
For example:

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
arrayList.add("smth");
```